# prismati joint movement by accelerometer change

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, accelerometer

I am developing a game where I have to move a basket shaped polygonal body in x axis on the bottom of the screen by accelerometer change.
horizontal prismatic joint is made connecting right wall body and basket body..once game started the basket body moves towards wall and stops....
How to make it move on accelerometer value change?

```
    prismaticJointDef.initialize(rightwallbody,  manBody, manBody.getWorldCenter(),     new Vector2(1f,0f));
    prismaticJointDef.collideConnected = false;
    prismaticJointDef.enableLimit = true;
    prismaticJointDef.localAxis1.nor();
    prismaticJointDef.localAxis1.set(1,0);

    prismaticJointDef.lowerTranslation = -150f /   PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;
    prismaticJointDef.upperTranslation = 150f /   PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;
    prismaticJointDef.enableMotor = true;

    prismaticJointDef.maxMotorForce = 100f;
    prismaticJointDef.motorSpeed = 0.1f;
    mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(prismaticJointDef);
```